# Selenium XPath finding more elements than actually in DOM

Tags: c#, html, unit-testing, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to loop through each table row element in the DOM and do a String Assert to see if it contains the desired text. When I debug my code and take a look at the Count of my variable tableRows, it shows that it contains 158 items when there are not nearly that many on the actual page. What am I doing wrong here?

C#:

```
[Test]
public void FilterByCompanyTest()
{
    const string filter = "Company";

    var table = this.Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("index-table"));
    var tableRows = table.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr"));

    for (var i = 1; i < tableRows.Count; i++) {
        StringAssert.Contains(filter, this.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[" + i + "]/td[6]")).Text);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="table-responsive index-table">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th class="ticket-title">Title</th>
                <th>


                    <a href="?companyID=-1&amp;technicianID=-1&amp;statusID=0&amp;typeID=&orderBy=priorityAsc">
                        Priority
                        <span class="unordered"></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>


                    <a href="?companyID=-1&amp;technicianID=-1&amp;statusID=0&amp;typeID=&orderBy=statusAsc">
                        Status
                        <span class="unordered"></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>


                    <a href="?companyID=-1&amp;technicianID=-1&amp;statusID=0&amp;typeID=&orderBy=dueDateAsc">
                        Due Date
                        <span class="unordered"></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>


                    <a href="?companyID=-1&amp;technicianID=-1&amp;statusID=0&amp;typeID=&orderBy=companyAsc">
                        Company
                        <span class="unordered"></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>


                    <a href="?companyID=-1&amp;technicianID=-1&amp;statusID=0&amp;typeID=&orderBy=technicianAsc">
                        Technician
                        <span class="unordered"></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr data-id="2">
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td class="ticket-title">
                                                Title
                    </td>
                    <td>Medium</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>7/19/2014<br /> <small>(3 changes)</small></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="modal-open" data-modal="company-details-modal" data-url="/companies/details/1612">Company</a></td>
                    <td>
Bill Billington                        
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="modal-open btn btn-sm btn-success" data-modal="edit-modal" data-url="/{controller}/edit/2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                        <a href="#" class="modal-open btn btn-sm btn-info" data-modal="log-modal" data-url="/{controller}/log/2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></a>
                        <a href="#" class="modal-open btn btn-sm btn-warning" data-modal="addtime-modal" data-url="/{controller}/addtime/2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-id="9">
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td class="ticket-title">
 <span class="work-on-ticket-note-icon-tickets" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" title="test"></span>                                                 Fix this thing!
                    </td>
                    <td>Medium</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>7/23/2014<br /> <small>(1 change)</small></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="modal-open" data-modal="company-details-modal" data-url="/companies/details/1604">Company</a></td>
                    <td>
    Bill Billington                        
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
                                    <br /><small>Checked In By Bill Billington</small>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="modal-open btn btn-sm btn-success" data-modal="edit-modal" data-url="/{controller}/edit/9"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                            <a href="#" class="modal-open btn btn-sm btn-info" data-modal="log-modal" data-url="/{controller}/log/9"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></a>
                            <a href="#" class="modal-open btn btn-sm btn-warning" data-modal="addtime-modal" data-url="/{controller}/addtime/9"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-id="10">
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td class="ticket-title">
                             <span class="work-on-ticket-note-icon-companies" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" title="This is a work on ticket note for a company!"></span>                         Test 
                        </td>
                        <td>Medium</td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td>7/22/2014<br /> <small>(0 changes)</small></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="modal-open" data-modal="company-details-modal" data-url="/companies/details/1">Company (Provider)</a></td>
                        <td>
        Bill Billington                        
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" class="modal-open btn btn-sm btn-success" data-modal="edit-modal" data-url="/{controller}/edit/10"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                                <a href="#" class="modal-open btn btn-sm btn-info" data-modal="log-modal" data-url="/{controller}/log/10"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></a>
                                <a href="#" class="modal-open btn btn-sm btn-warning" data-modal="addtime-modal" data-url="/{controller}/addtime/10"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: `//` in the middle of an XPath expression means to search among descendants of what comes before `//`. `//` at the beginning of an XPath expression means to search among descendants of the root node; i.e. search the whole document. That's why you need to start your XPath with `.//`; `.` means the current context node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath needs a little more of a helping hand to tell it about contexts (i.e searching within an element):

```
var tableRows = table.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tr"));
```

Notice the **.**. This will filter the query down to only `tr` elements within that table.

The other thing to note is this can be done without XPath:

var tableRows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

I will also mention that in terms of performance, you may find targeting the elements specifically through XPath (i.e **not** for looping around the whole lot) will be much quicker and more performant.